# Renaming open MXD using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, mxd

Is there a method in ArcPy that will rename the MXD you **currently have open**? I don't want to use `mxd.saveACopy("newFileName")` as it will just save a COPY with a new name, not rename the current MXD.

Basically I want a method that will replicate the File > Save As > "newFileName.mxd" process.

**os.rename()** wont work, as the document is currently open.

Is this just a simple case of *can't be done with ArcPy, use ArcObjects*?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  this is an operating system rather than spatial software limitation.

Answer (score -1):

As [commented by @MichaelStimson](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/126865/renaming-open-mxd-using-arcpy#comment181693_126865):

> Unfortunately due to file access (the MXD is open) you cannot rename
>   it by any method. In order to perform a rename you need to close the
>   file... this is an operating system limitation not an arcpy or python
>   limitation. As a workaround you can save a copy then delete the
>   original.

[and when asked about ArcObjects instead of ArcPy/Python]

> No, the operating system will not let you. When you open a file (in
>   this case MXD) the application (ArcMap) has locks placed on the file
>   by the underlying operating system which should be read lock; what
>   would happen if you opened a document and tried to rename it in
>   explorer? You get error 32 from the operating system. When you 'save a
>   copy' ArcMap doesn't switch to the new MXD, you need to do that
>   yourself; each instance of ArcMap can only have one MXD open so the
>   old one is closed (locks removed) which can then be deleted if you
>   wish.